# Prove that $\sum_{j=0}^R {R+N-j-1 \choose N-1}(j+1) = {N+R+1 \choose N+1}, \quad N \geq 1, R \geq 0$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I have written $\sum_{j=0}^R {R+N-j-1 \choose N-1}(j+1)$ as ${N-1 \choose N-1}(R+1) + {N \choose N-1}(R) + \dots + {R+N-1 \choose N-1}(1)$. This then turns into

$$\frac{1}{0!}(R+1) + \frac{N}{1!}(R) + \frac{N(N+1)}{2!}(R-1) + \dots + \frac{N(N+1)\dots(N+R)}{R!}(1),$$

which seems promising, since the right hand side of the equation is equal to $\frac{(N+R+1)!}{(N+1)!(R!)}$, and a common denominator with $R!$ can be created. That being said, I haven't been able to get this expansion anywhere, so I'm looking for either a trick with it or another method to prove this identity. The identity is backed by WolframAlpha ([here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bj%3D0%7D%5ER+%7BR%2BN-j-1+%5Cchoose+N-1%7D%28j%2B1%29+%3D+%7BN%2BR%2B1+%5Cchoose+N%2B1%7D)), so I know it's true. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a combinatorial proof, count the $(N+1)$-subsets of $\{1,\dots,N+R+1\}$. The RHS is clear. For the LHS, count according to the second smallest element $j+2$.  Then there are $\binom{j+1}{1}$ choices for the smallest element and $\binom{N+R+1-(j+2)}{N+1-2}$ choices for the remaining elements.  Hence
$$\sum_j \binom{j+1}{1} \binom{N+R+1-(j+2)}{N+1-2} = \binom{N+R+1}{N+1}.$$

Comment: I apologize... I've heard of this approach before (and I admittedly don't really understand it), but how exactly does it relate to solving the problem?

Comment: A combinatorial proof proves an identity by counting the same objects in two different ways. I added more detail to make my answer clearer.